# Conditionally include a JSP .tag file?

Tags: java, jsp-tags, conditional-statements

Been trying to look for an answer on the web, but couldn't find it.
I have a jsp page calling a tag file (below), and inside this tag file, I need to conditionally call another tag file. However, the content is include no matter what value I passed through **$loadScript**.

In my jsp page, I pass in the value of **loadScript**: (updated)

```
<jsp:attribute name="loadScript">false</jsp:attribute>
```

This is what's in my tag file:

```
<%@tag description="put the tag description here" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ attribute name="loadScript"%>
<%@ taglib tagdir="/WEB-INF/tags" prefix="main" %>

<html>
<head>
<c:if test="${loadScript == 'true'}">
    <main:script></main:script>  
</c:if>

</head>
</html>
```

What is the proper way to conditionally call/include a tag file?

update:
Yes, I can confirm the value had successfully transferred using this test:

```
<c:if test="${'loadScript'}">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        alert(${loadScript});
    </script>
</c:if>
```

It looks like `<main:script></main:script>` tag would get generate no matter what?

Comment: Do you only use JSP or is JSF also a possibility? Otherwise You could look into a4j:include and use the rendered method to include some content.

Comment: could you first confirm if the value `loadScript` is ever transferred at all.

Comment: yes, the value transferred over, see updated code. but no matter what i do, the alert would pop-up regardless of true/false I use.